# How to make that on top of my column would be displayed data labels?

Tags: php, laravel, charts, chart.js

After searching documentation about 2 hours and not finding a answer (https://charts.erik.cat/), maybe someone will help me with this... I'm using Laravel Charts chart.js library. How to make that on top of my column would be displayed data labels? like in this picture on DC coulmn: [image]

This is my code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Content;
use App\Charts\UserLineChart;
use Charts;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ChartController extends Controller
{

  public function index(Request $request)
  {
    $content = Content::where('vei_sn', '23333')->get();
    if ($request->has('date_from') && $request->input('date_from') != '' && $request->has('date_to') && $request->input('date_to') != '') {
        $datefrom = $request->input('date_from');
        $dateto = $request->input('date_to');
        $content = $content->whereBetween('op_date', [$datefrom, $dateto]);
    }

      $OBD = $content->where('con_type', 'OBD')->count();
      $DC = $content->where('con_type', 'DC')->count();
      $BSL = $content->where('con_type', 'BSL')->count();
      $content = $content->pluck('con_type', 'con_type');

      $pChart = new UserLineChart;
      $bChart = new UserLineChart;

      $pChart->labels($content->values())->minimalist($display = true);
      $bChart->labels($content->values());
      $pChart->dataset('Connections', 'pie', [$OBD, $DC, $BSL]);
      $bChart->dataset('Connections', 'bar', [$OBD, $DC, $BSL])->options([
        'fill' => false,
      ]);
      return view('chart.index', compact('pChart', 'bChart'));
  }
}
```